# Add multiple New products to website programmatically woocommerce Using PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have 3000 products to upload to the website so am trying to add products programmatically to my woocommerce website got some code which add's products programmatically am new to this i have no idea how to run this and where to run this am stucked in between the a small help will be appreciated a lot where to run the code and how to add the multiple products to website .

```
$post = array(
 'post_author' => $user_id,
 'post_content' => '',
 'post_status' => "publish",
 'post_title' => $product->part_num,
 'post_parent' => '',
 'post_type' => "product",

 );
  //Create post
 $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
 if($post_id){
 $attach_id = get_post_meta($product->parent_id, "_thumbnail_id", true);
 add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
}
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Races', 'product_cat' );
 wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');



 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
 update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0');
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', "" );
```

Comment: You might want to try out the woocommerce API: http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product  There's also the bulk creator: http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-update-multiple-products

Comment: @Dez thanks for the reply so got some clue how to upload the product if you can elaborate with an example would be more helpful to me to understand this

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question shows how to programmatically add products to Woocommerce: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137501/how-to-add-product-in-woocommerce-with-php-code